# Does a select box with a size attribute work with $_POST?

Tags: php, html, size, forms

I have a fairly straightforward use of SQL and PHP to generate a select box of options. I originally had the select box with a size attribute and could not figure out why the `$_POST` after the form was submitted was always coming up not set. Eventually I ended up trying it without a `size` attribute, and it worked. To confirm, I went back to the select box I originally intended, set a size attribute, noted that it failed to set the `$_POST` variable, and then the ONLY thing I did was delete `size='10'` from the tag, and it worked as intended.

Here is the code with the attribute in place.

```
<select name='select_news' size='10'>
  <?php
    foreach($news_dates_list as $date)
    {
      echo ("<option value='".$date['month']."/".$date['day']."/".$date['year']."'>".$date['month']."/".$date['day']."/".$date['year']."</option>");
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

When the form is submitted, and it attempts to access `$_POST['select_news']`, it generates the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: select_news in C:\website\admin\index.php on line 310. When I delete ONLY the "size='10'" part, it does not generate an error and works as expected.

So I'm just looking for confirmation as to whether or not it is correct that a size attribute in a select box causes the select box to malfunction when you attempt to access it via `$_POST`. If it should not have this effect, does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: I think it may send as an array when allowed multiple values. Try to use `var_dump`

Comment: size attribute has nothing to do with $_POST variable, it may be something else? add some code. size is just an option to display items at a time.

Comment: Maybe show us the code where you actually attempt to use the variable and not just `$_POST['select_news']`, might help us help you. Because I see the error is on line 310, there might be more relevant code that we should see

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but change:

```
echo ("<option value='".$date['month']."/".$date['day']."/".$date['year']."'>".$date['month']."/".$date['day']."/".$date['year']."</option>");
```

To:

```
echo "<option value='{$date['month']}/{$date['day']}/{$date['year']}'>{$date['month']}/{$date['day']}/{$date['year']}</option>";
```

i.e. don't use parenthesis with echo, and use `{}` to interpolate variables inside a quoted string without having to constantly start/stop the strings.

---

Size has nothing to do with what is returned. Something else is changing. I suggest two things:

1. Take a look at the generated soruce code - perhaps you messed up your quoting in some way.
2. do `print_r($_RESULT)` and see what's there

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name from `select_news` to `select_news[]`, like when you have multiple checkboxes with the same name.